# FormApp - Alternative to switch statement?

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there an alternative (faster, simpler) to a switch statement for catching form submission responses and storing them as variables without being dependent on the index?

Background: This script will eventually email a bunch of different people based on some item response conditions.  I'm just helping a co-worker, so I don't own the form.  As such, I would like my script to not be based on question position, just question title.  I'm currently thinking that I need to store responses as variables for readability when it comes time to create the conditions that will generate emails.  This is just a simple example, but the actual form is about 25 questions over 10 sections.

```js
function onSubmit(e) {

  var formResponse = e.response;
  var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();

  for (var i = 0; i < itemResponses.length; i++) {
    var itemResponse = itemResponses[i];
    
    switch (itemResponse.getItem().getTitle()) {
      case 'Name:':
        var studentName = itemResponse.getResponse();
        break;
      case 'Email Address:':
        var email = itemResponse.getResponse();
        break;
    }
  }
  
  console.log(studentName + ' ' + email);
}
```

Comment: It would be much easier to do it from the response spreadsheet and use the header row to identify the columns?

Comment: @JamesD There will be thousands of form submissions, so I thought it would be simpler to run the conditions once, when the form was submitted, rather than having it go through all the submissions on the response sheet.

Comment: If I run from the response sheet, would I need to add a flag or something to let the script know which form responses were new, and which had already been processed?

Comment: @ZachG the number of submissions won't make much of a difference (up to the max cell count) there are some risks that the script may not execute successfully and then trying to troubleshoot and pick up on any missed submissions will be difficult (an incorrect email address for example). The onSubmit on the sheet would still work in the same way, it will only process the submitted row, but adding a flag allows you to build a log of the submissions and easily resend any submissions if you need to.

Comment: @JamesD Thanks!  I'll rewrite it from the other side of things.

Comment: @L1ghtk3ira, this is what I was thinking of, I just was asking too narrowly.

Comment: Between both of your responses, I can take if from here.  Thanks for the help.  How do I mark this closed without answer outside of replies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Flow:

- Create a alias[Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/map) of all itemResponses' title => alias
- Create a another responseMap of [alias, response].
- You can get  any response  from it's alias through the responseMap

#### Script:

```
/**
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Events.FormsOnFormSubmit} e
 */

function onSubmit(e) {
  const formResponse = e.response;
  const itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
  const aliasMap = new Map([
    ['Name:', 'studentName'], //[title,alias]
    ['Email Address:', 'email'],
  ]);
  const responseMap = new Map();
  itemResponses.forEach(response =>
    responseMap.set(
      aliasMap.get(response.getItem().getTitle()),
      response.getResponse()
    )
  );

  console.info(responseMap.get('studentName') + ' ' + responseMap.get('email'));
}
```